# Using jsp templates in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, templates

I have a web project that was built using Rational Application Developer. Most of my pages are built using a template file (jtpl).

I am switching the IDE to Eclipse Juno, I noticed that in eclipse templates are created differently. You have to go to preferences and create a template there.

I think also the syntax is different. what I have right now in my jtpl file is something like this:

```
<%-- tpl:insert attribute="imports" --%>

<%-- /tpl:insert --%>
```

Not sure if this will work with eclipse as is or not.

Rational was very good at managing templates. the second I add the import statement on the top of the jsp, rational inserts all the code from the templates for me (dimmed so I cannot change it in the jsp) and all I have to do is to fill the parts I need.

Also with Rational if I make one change to the template and save it, all the jsps using it are updated with the change.

My questions are:

1) is there a way to use the current template without much changes when switching to eclipse?

2) this is very important too, is there a way to automatically update all the pages using a template when a change is made to it ?

3) any good examples of using, updating templates with eclipse?

Comment: I realise this question is over 2 years old and had no answer on the forum.  We are running into same situation and I was wondering if you found answers to your questions above elsewhere and if so, could you share them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation, and after looking for a solution for several days, I've come to the conclusion (based on not finding any solution), that this is a "IBM only" feature.